# Android Softkeyboard Issue

Tags: java, android, soft-keyboard

I have an EditText widget in my main activity. when the EditText widget get the focus, the soft key board displays, when the EditText widget loses the focus. However, I want to display the soft key board  all the time, until the main activity is Destroy. How to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself? Nobody will write a code snippet here for you. Try it yourself, if you'll got error then paste your code snippet along with logs here.

Answer (score 0):

//To show softkeyboard

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

//try this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_‌​VISIBLE);
```

Comment: But the soft key board will disappear, when the edit text loses focus

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding following to activity tag in your manifest file

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```